# Why don't my jQuery functions work to hide/show elements?

Tags: jquery, function, show-hide

My first function to hide the question until the start button is clicked works.
The second function works which shows the first quiz question and hides the start quiz button.
After that, upon answering the first question, I want to display the next question and hide the first question, but it doesn't work.

```
    <button id="btn1">High Scores</button>
    <button id="btn2">Start Quiz</button>
    
    <p class='question1'>Question 1:<br><br>
        "What does HTML stand for?"<br><br>
        <button id="btnA">A  Hyper text Markeup Language</button><br>
        <button id="btnB">B Hyperlinks and Text Markup Languages</button><br>
        <button id="btnC">C Home Tool Markup Language</button><br></p>
        
    <p class='question2'>Question 2:<br><br>
        "What does CSS stand for?"<br><br>
        <button id="btn2A">A  Completely Self Sufficient</button><br>
        <button id="btn2B">B Computer Style Sheet</button><br>
        <button id="btn2C">C Cascading Style Sheet</button><br></p>

    <p class='question3'>Question 3:<br><br>
        "What is the purpose of a Bootcamp?"<br><br>
        <button id="btn3A">A  To teach you perseverance</button><br>
        <button id="btn3B">B To teach you to find your own solutions</button><br>
        <button id="btn3C">C Both A and B</button><br></p>

    <p class='question4'>Question 3:<br><br>
        "What is the correct way to link a javascript file?"<br><br>
        <button id="btn4A">A  Make sure it appears within the body section</button><br>
        <button id="btn4B">B Use the script tags</button><br>
        <button id="btn4C">C There is no need for a link, html finds it on its own</button><br></p>  
</div>

<script>
var score = 0

    // hides the question until start quiz is clicked
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.question1').hide();
    });

    // start button is clicked, shows the first question and hides start button
    $('#btn2').on('click', function() {
        $('.question1').show();
        $('#btn2').hide();
    });

    // When an answer is clicked, the question gets hidden and the next question is shown.
    $('#btnA').on('click', function() {
        $('.question1').hide();
        $('.question2').show();
        score++
    });

    $('#btnB').on('click', function(){
        $('.question1').hide();
        $('.question2').show();
    });

    $('#btnC').on('click', function(){
        $('.question1').hide();
        $('.question2').show();
    });


    
</script>
```

Comment: You do not have any bindings on the ids past the first question.  Clicking those buttons will do nothing unless you make them do something.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is gonna be very long if you do it this way.

You can do the whole work in these lines

```
// For adding scores
$('#btnA, #btn2B, #btn3x, ....').click(function() { 
  score++; 
});

// for hiding and showing 
// do change all classes to just 'question'
// or use [class^=question] as the selector
$('.question > button').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide().next('.question').show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I dont really understand your solution since I have just started working with javascript and jquery. At this point I'm learning and Its ok if my code is long, I will improve it when I know how to do it better. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your button triggers are outside of your DO READY

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.question1').hide();
    //});// close this at the end...

    // start button is clicked, shows the first question and hides start button
    $('#btn2').on('click', function() {
        $('.question1').show();
        $('#btn2').hide();
    });

    // When an answer is clicked, the question gets hidden and the next question is shown.
    $('#btnA').on('click', function() {
        $('.question1').hide();
        $('.question2').show();
        score++
    });

    $('#btnB').on('click', function(){
        $('.question1').hide();
        $('.question2').show();
    });

    $('#btnC').on('click', function(){
        $('.question1').hide();
        $('.question2').show();
    });
}); // close dom ready here
```